# Restoring postgres sql file over 20gb

Tags: database, postgresql

We have a backup of a database with sql 32gb format (containing various binary files over 50mb), but when we do import data only 8gb are actually placed on the bench.

We've done everything from changing the version that was Postgres 8.3 to Postgres 9.1 and even then not everything is imported.

Comment: Did you try to chunk the SQL file? Why not making up chunks of say 1 GB and then apply the first, then the second, ... until the 32nd chunk. That should be no problem since SQL is plain text.

Comment: Is there any error message involved?

Comment: And what is the problem? Any data missing?

Comment: There is a semicolon missing on line#42,

Comment: How are you determining that not everything was imported? What's the exact restore command line you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be normal for Postgres.

When you export your binary data to sql file it must be encoded as `base64` and properly escaped. This encoding and escaping can increase the size of the output file 2-6 times (from my experience). + sql dump format adds overhead for `INSERT`/`COPY` commands.

Try dumping the base in binary format, to see what size would the binary dump be.